# How do you resolve a domain name to an IP address with .NET/C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dns, reverse-dns

How do you resolve a domain name to an IP address with .NET/C#?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
using System.Net;

foreach (IPAddress address in Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.google.com"))
{
   Console.WriteLine(address.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [System.Net.Dns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns) class